# VB6 dbgrid's setting automatically disappearing

Tags: vb6, activex, dbgrid

I use VB6 dbgrid (in windows 7). But since last couple of days the columns of dbgrids have been squeezing automatically even after fixing them.

[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRUGZ.png)
[Retrieving the Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkxkI.png)

Comment: That's design view - what does is look like in runtime? What properties are set by default and what are set by code?

Comment: Same thing is happening.

Comment: There is no code. Only I have connected to an access database thru DAO data control and trying to populate the records. Should I reinstall vb6?

Answer (score 0):

Try these two things:
    Create a new Datagrid 
Or 
    Right click on the Datagrid and click retrieve properties.

See if that works for you.

Comment: what if you create a new data grid in a new project (just to see if the problem is within that particular project or the whole of VB6) and see if that goes well.

Comment: Same problem for both old and new projects. Whole VB6 is acting like this. What to do? I have also reinstalled VB6 once.

Comment: Have you searched online for this issue as i have never come across it before.

Comment: No, I didn't search it much. What to do? I think it has some link with Window's display setting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently on a laptop which have been using for several years without problems. All my projects using dbgrid loose the column settings after closing and reopening the project. I did a search on my c drive for dbgrid32.ocx and noted that I had more than one on my computer and all had same date and size except for one located in my windows/syswow64 folder, which incidentally was the one VB6 was using. I used regsvr32 to unregister it, replaced it with one of the others and registered it with regsvr32 and now everything is back to normal. So all had happened because something replaced my ocx with a faulty one.